# How to add a dynamic css class inside a html class attribute in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a div like this:

```
<div class="row loginCtrl.padding(50)"></div>
```

My controller code goes like this:

```
app.controller("loginController", function(){

  this.padding = function(val){
    alert('padding-top-'+val);
  }

});
```

i know that padding function will be only called on a event like click etc

Comment: You should use `ng-class` for this

Comment: I new to angularjs. It could help me if you post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ng-class` for this

```
<div class="row" ng-class="loginCtrl.padding(50)"></div> 



app.controller("loginController", function(){

 this.padding = function(val){
    return 'padding-top-'+val;
   }

});
```

Comment: hi, can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45385280/placed-debugger-inside-tha-function-changelistener-tocheck-whether-its-going-ins

Comment: excusme @texirv. may be create a demo people can help you.

Comment: Hey mine is a huge codebase not able to include all the files